# Ajax add to cart on product page - Success message Woocommerce

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled ajax add to cart in my functions.php and it's working so well. The only thing is that the success message has now disappeared.

I used this code to add the ajax to the page - is there a way i can keep the ajax functionality but also get the success message (ie. product has been added to cart) Thank you so much. x

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'modify_woocommerce_get_script_data', 20, 2 );

function modify_woocommerce_get_script_data ( $params, $handle ) {
    global $wp;

    $page_slug = '';
    $your_ajax_page_slug = 'your-page-slug';
    $current_url = home_url( $wp->request );

    // Break the URL by the delimiter
    $url_pieces = explode('/', $current_url);

    // Get the page slug
    if( is_array( $url_pieces ) )
        $page_slug = end( $url_pieces );

    if( $handle == 'wc-add-to-cart' && $page_slug == $your_ajax_page_slug ) {
        $params['cart_redirect_after_add'] = false;
    }

    return $params;
}
```

Comment: Actually my bad please close this, it's workign x

Comment: You can delete your post.